# Celery task calling itself after task succeeds without celerybeat

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I want to call my celery task occasionally like every 30minutes after the current task done, But sometimes task takes longer than expected because of task is downloading files from remote server. So I don't want to use celeryBeat. Also, using self. retry is only for when the error occurred I suppose. Here is my task:

```
@shared_task(name="download_big", bind=True, acks_late=true, autoretry_for=(Exception, requests.exceptiosn.RequestException), retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 4, "countdown": 3}):
def download_big(self):
    my_file = session.get('example.com/hello.mp4')
    if my_file.status_code == requests.codes["OK"]:
        open("hello.mp4", "wb").write(my_file.content)
    else:
        self.retry()
```

Update:

Well i changed my structure to this:

```
@shared_task(name="download_big", bind=True, acks_late=true, autoretry_for=(Exception, requests.exceptiosn.RequestException), retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 4, "countdown": 3}):
def download_big(url):
    my_file = session.get(url, name)
    if my_file.status_code == requests.codes["OK"]:
        open(name, "wb").write(my_file.content)
    else:
        self.retry()

@shared_task(name="download_all", bind=True, acks_late=true, autoretry_for=(Exception, requests.exceptiosn.RequestException), retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 4, "countdown": 3}):
def download_all(self):
    my_list = [...]  # bunch of urls with names
    jobs = []
    for name, url in my_list:
        jobs.append(download_big.si(url, name))
    group(jobs)()
```

So in this case, i have to call download_all method instead of download_big, that way i can download file in parallel and when all the group tasks done it needs to be call itself again after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=group#celery.chord) which will run a group of tasks and when they complete, will run a callback which you can use to reschedule.

e.g.

```py
from celery import chord

@shared_task(name="download_big", bind=True, acks_late=true, autoretry_for=(Exception, requests.exceptiosn.RequestException), retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 4, "countdown": 3}):
def download_big(url):
    my_file = session.get(url, name)
    if my_file.status_code == requests.codes["OK"]:
        open(name, "wb").write(my_file.content)
    else:
        self.retry()

@shared_task(name="download_all", bind=True, acks_late=true, autoretry_for=(Exception, requests.exceptiosn.RequestException), retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 4, "countdown": 3}):
def download_all(self):
    my_list = [...]  # bunch of urls with names
    jobs = []
    for name, url in my_list:
        jobs.append(download_big.si(url, name))

    # Run the group and reschedule once all tasks complete
    chord(jobs)(download_all.apply_async(countdown=1800))
```

Comment: Uhm, is it gonna call itself when download has not finished? what about the case when instead of downloading a file inside this task, i call group of download task? that way group called and then none of the file has finished, download_big call itself again?

Comment: Well the call to schedule itself happens after the file is written which I assume means download completed? For the `download_all()` you may be able to use a chord, which allows you to specify a callback when the tasks complete. In the callback you could reschedule the group. I'll update the answer.

Comment: this throwing `Retry in 4s: AttributeError("'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'clone'",` to me